# weblogic wseeclient.jar i want an alternative jar for JBOSS while migrating from weblogic server to jboss

Tags: jar, jboss, migration, weblogic, subject-alternative-name

I am trying to migrate my Application from weblogic server to JBoss in that wseeclient.jar i want an alternative jar for JBOSS

I searched in google for long time i cant able find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

The 'wseeclient.jar' is utilised by a JAX-WS client application. Try to use the JAX-WS API instead of any WebLogic Server specific APIS with client applications.